# Project deployed on heroku works wrong with routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I deployed project on Heroku.

It was working well on dev, but on production it has problems with routing. It always tries to use server api routes on client side. What is wrong with this code?

```
app.use("/api/games", games);
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

I also wrote Heroku-postbuild script in package.json

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Client side works on React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scripts list in `package.json` I added engines with `node` and `npm` versions and it started to work well

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run app in production mode or set NODE_ENV to production.

I think this `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` will run your app in development mode so you have to set it to `true` ( `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` ).

Please also print `process.env.NODE_ENV` before if statement to check your env mode.

Comment: It is.production mode. Problem somewhere in app.use, app.get

Comment: Please mention an example, what are you doing, the expected result, the actual result